# Extending the JSTL View class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am extending the JSTL view class to implement my own view resolver. But, I am having the problem. Look into my code:

```
public class TestView extends JstlView {
    private String fo_suffix = "_jo";

    public void setUrl(String url)
    {
        //We need to change the inputed url to add a prefix for fo
        super.setUrl(url.replace("\\.jsp", fo_suffix+ ".jsp"));
    }
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        final StringWriter xmlfo = new StringWriter();

        HttpServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(
                response) {
            @Override
            public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
                return new PrintWriter(xmlfo);
            }
        };



        super.render(model, request, wrapper);
```

In the above code, when i am debugging, the control never comes to the **setUrl** method. So the url is always null in the internal RequestDispatcher.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to put TestView in "myServletName"-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="test.TestView"/>
....
```